# Is possible to have multiple data requests in Octobercms form?

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, laravel-form

I have this data-request from Mailchimp plugin where I send form data to Mailchimp API.

```
 <form data-request="{{ mailSignup }}::onSignup"
       data-request-update="'{{ mailSignup }}::result': '#{{ mailSignup.id }}container'" class="book" id="bookit">
```

> Is there a way to join another **data-request** from Mail plugin
>   (genericFrom)?

This data-request send's e-mail on form submit.
Goal is to have two data-requests in the same form.

First request have to send form data to Mailchimp API and second request should send E-mail.

```
<form data-request="{{ genericForm }}::onFormSubmit">
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<form data-request="{{ mailSignup }}::onSignup, {{ genericForm }}::onFormSubmit"
       data-request-update="'{{ mailSignup }}::result': '#{{ mailSignup.id }}container'" class="book" id="bookit">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with the javascript api instead of using the data-request attributes.

[Check here for documents][1] [1]: https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $(this).request('{{ mailSignup }}::onSignup', {
       /* Update or send data */
    })
    $(this).request('{{ genericForm }}::onFormSubmit', {
       /* Update or send data */
    })
});
```